# Re-generate i18n.dart file

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization

*I've just migrated a legacy project to null Safety :*

- I'd like to re-generate the  `i18n.dart` file - the thing is I have *no clue* which commands to use to do so :

Do I have to use a package ?

Here is what my file looks like :

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names
// ignore_for_file: camel_case_types
// ignore_for_file: prefer_single_quotes

// This file is automatically generated. DO NOT EDIT, all your changes would be lost.
class S implements WidgetsLocalizations {
  const S();

  static S current;

  static const GeneratedLocalizationsDelegate delegate = GeneratedLocalizationsDelegate();

  static S of(BuildContext context) => Localizations.of<S>(context, S);

  @override
  TextDirection get textDirection => TextDirection.ltr;
}

class $en extends S {
  const $en();
}

class GeneratedLocalizationsDelegate extends LocalizationsDelegate<S> {
  const GeneratedLocalizationsDelegate();

  List<Locale> get supportedLocales {
    return const <Locale>[
      Locale("en", ""),
    ];
  }

[...]



String getLang(Locale l) =>
    l == null ? null : l.countryCode != null && l.countryCode.isEmpty ? l.languageCode : l.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout the project's `dev_dependencies` if it is using `intl_utils` package update that package as well to the null-safety version and run command

`flutter pub run intl_utils:generate`

it should regenerate the code from the localized values in `.arb` files in your project

Comment: it's not using `int_utils` I found `easy_localization` you think this might be it ? which command should I use with it ? 

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization#-code-generation

Comment: this don't work @mmcdon20 : /

Comment: well obviously it worked before migrating it to null-safety since generated code is there to prove it. my suggestion is try to go through easy_localization config docs step by step and reconfigure your project. and have you update the easy_localization version?